# WPF MVVM Light - Multiple Data Grids and passing values

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, mvvm-light, datacontext

I don't have any code currently, but I need to make an admin screen for my WPF 4.5 project that is using MVVM Light.  The design has a left hand column with all of the objects you can edit.  The right hand side is a data grid with all the values, columns, etc that are currently in the database.  I was just curious what the best way to architect this would be.  I had imagined using a singular datagrid that you can switch the datacontext on but I am still fairly new to WPF and MVVM Light.  One thing I know for sure is that we do not want to use Auto Generate Columns because each table has different columns and we do not want to use the column names from the database.

Comment: You could use a `ContentControl` for the right side and have one `DataGrid` per objects, that you would switch when the user selection change. It will be more or less relevant depending on the number of objects and the way you generate the grids...

Comment: Thank you, that will definitely help.

Comment: Use Entity Framework or create your own custom classes. Then the names of your properties don't have to be the same as the Database column names and you could use autogenerate columns? You'll want classes instead of a DataSet either way if you plan to use the MVVM design pattern.

Comment: Pragmateek's suggestion is a good one as well and probably how I would do it. I rarely use Autogenerate columns.